# Java NIO read() never throws exception OR returns -1

Tags: java, nio

I have set up a basic client app that creates a Socket to connect and send a few bytes to my NIO server. It opens, writes bytes, closes, program terminates.

On the server side, however, my Selector is spinning over this key endlessly returning 0 bytes read causing the SocketChannel to never close.

I was under the impression that when a client socket was closed (on the client side) that would cause either read() to return -1 or throw an exception (on the server side).

Comment: Please edit your question and include a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I wasn't doing anything with the ByteBuffer after SocketChannel.read(buf)

Even if the remote socket is closed, so long as there's still data in the buffer, the local socket is still ready